# Move/Push page.main.title block into Breadcrumbs Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, phtml

I want to move **page.main.title** block to my breadcrumbs container, not before or after it, I want to **push it inside breadcrumbs template** and remove other wheres.

So this is my **~/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/breadcrumbs.phtml** :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <span class="current-name">
            <?php
                 /*** I NEED PAGE.MAIN.TITLE BLOCK HERE ***/
            ?>
        </span>
        <ul class="items">
            <?php /* showing breadcrumb items */ ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**in above template in .current-name class I need the title block!**

I did this in **~/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**, but *it goes before breadcrumbs block not inside it*:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs"/>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and I did this in **breadcrumbs.phtml** too, It works perfectly but *the Title exists in other wheres and I have 2 `<h1>` tag in my page*, so that is wrong!:

```
echo $block->getBlockHtml('page.main.title');
```

and I want to use this block(page.main.title) for showing my title Because of SEO stuff and I think this is the proper way! not the bad ways like show title from latest crumb label in loop or anything like that!

**Note** that the '~' character above is pointing my theme folder (`app/design/frontend/MyVendor/myTheme`).

**Note** that I'm using `Magento 2.1.9` with `PHP 7.0.24`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below way,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="breadcrumbs" before="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**Edit:**

Then you need to use `echo $block->getChildHtml('page.main.title');` in everywhere of your **breadcrumbs.phtml** file.

*But I don't know better way to do that!*

Comment: After use your code, every titles disappeared! it worked like `remove="true"` in layout xml. But after that using **echo $block->getChildHtml('page.main.title');**, It worked. and show title in there. but is this a proper way?!

Comment: Try with updated code

Comment: The new one, moved title of page in bottom of products list. not Breadcrumbs!

Answer (score 1):

Here I achieved this line by using below line, If you have the same requirement you can use this line of code.

```
<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="main.content" before="-"/>
```

I hope it may help you. find the reference image below.

[image]